# What's the usage of `Multiply Const 1` and `Multiply Const 0`?

Tags: software-defined-radio, gnuradio

Based on [Gnuradio](https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php?title=Multiply_Const),

> Multiplies the input stream by a scalar or vector constant
> (element-wise if vector).
>
> output = input * constant

In above web page, I found `Multiply Const 0`,is that means signal totally disappear?  And sometimes,I saw `Multiply Const 1`,is it equal to the origin signal?

What's the usage of `Multiply Const 1` and `Multiply Const 0`?

Answer (score 5):

The wiki page you link to has two examples of how this block can be put to use. (I think the wiki image and the text are out of sync with each other because the text refers to a third use of the **Multiply Const** block which my eyes are not seeing.) Both of the "constants" are actually modified at runtime by other blocks.

In the first case, it is being used as a Transmit/Receive switch, where it either passes the signal or it does not based on a GUI element. There is a **Note** above that **Multiply Const** block that indicates that the constant value is 1 to enable transmit. This implies the block is being used as a simple switch; const 1 should output whatever is at the input and const 0 should output no signal.

The second example we are told the constant is being modified by a **QT GUI Range** block to adjust the final volume of the signal going into the **Audio Sink** via a **Multiply** block.

It may be instructive to think of this block as holding a value that is constant to itself. The block will not adjust its own constant state, but it can be changed from the outside by other blocks.